# Fill a DataFrame with medians of group only for cell containing specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find a **nice/smart** way to fill my DataFrame with median value from groups.
I have 2 groups "I" and "J" and 2 factors"A" and "B". I want to replace my negative value by the median of the group to which the value belongs.
One constraint is that I don't want to replace the NaN values.
Here is the code to make my initial DataFrame

```
tuples = [('I','0'), ('I','1'), ('I', '2'), ('J', '3'), ('I', '4'), ('J', '5')]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["Id1", "Id2"])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(-1, 2), columns=['A', 'B'], index=index)
df["A"].iloc[0]=-1
df["B"].iloc[-1:]=-1
df["B"].iloc[-2]=18
df["B"].iloc[0]=np.NaN
df["B"].iloc[1]=np.NaN
```

which gives:

```
A   B
Id1 Id2     
I   0   -1  NaN
    1   2   NaN
    2   4   5.0
J   3   6   7.0
I   4   8   18.0
J   5   10  -1.0
```

Here is the way I solved it:

```
ind, col = np.where(df<0)
nb_df_lt_0 = len(ind)
for ii in np.arange(nb_df_lt_0) : 
    df.iloc[ind[ii],col[ii]] = np.NAN
    xx, yy = ind[ii], col[ii]
    index_Id1 = df.index.get_level_values("Id1")[xx]
    df.iloc[xx,yy] = df.loc[index_Id1,:].iloc[:,yy].median()
df
```

This gives what I was looking for:

```
A   B
Id1 Id2     
I   0   4.0  NaN
    1   2.0  NaN
    2   4.0  5.0
J   3   6.0  7.0
I   4   8.0  18.0
J   5   10.0 7.0
```

It works, but it doesn't look nice, and surely not very efficient since I have a `For` loop.
I would be very please to look at a solution with pandas or numpy functions which make the job.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
df.mask(df<0, df.mask(df<0, np.nan).groupby(level=0).median())
```

Lets break that down.  You need the median of the two groups "I" and "J" excluding the negative values:

```py
median_df = df.mask(df<0, np.nan).groupby(level=0).median()
```

Then you want to substitute the median for the negative values in the original DataFrame:

```py
df.mask(df<0, median_df)
```

Comment: Terrific, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

It groups each col and then finds the median of the group (not including the -1 values.)

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df.groupby('Id1')[col].apply(lambda x: (
        x.replace(-1, x.loc[x != -1].median())
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from a small correction in the way you created the source DataFrame:
As each column can contain *NaN*, which is a special case of **float**,
create the temporary DataFrame with data type of *float*:

```
np.arange(12, dtype='float')
```

(no change in the rest of your code to create the DataFrame).

You will need the following group processing function:

```
def grpProc(grp):
    grp[grp == -1] = grp[grp != -1].median()
    return grp
```

It computes the *median* from elements != *0* and saves it in elements ==
*-1*, assuming that the source group (*grp*) is a part of the current column
for each *Id1*.
Then the changed group is returned.

And to get the result, apply it to each column of your DataFrame,
grouped by *Id1* (level 0):

```
result = df.apply(lambda col: col.groupby(level=0).apply(grpProc))
```

No *axis* parameter has been passed, so this function is applied to
each **column** (*axis == 0*).

For your sample data the result is:

```
            A     B
Id1 Id2            
I   0     4.0   NaN
    1     2.0   NaN
    2     4.0   5.0
J   3     6.0   7.0
I   4     8.0  18.0
J   5    10.0   7.0
```